# ArrayList Element Comparison

Tags: asp.net, arraylist

I have a ArrayList with five Numbers, for an example 1,2,3,4,5. Same number can not be repeated. How can I check it?

Comment: which language c# or vb? and which asp.net version?

Comment: Q: why are you using an ArrayList rather than a Generic type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do Arraylist.Contains() method to check whether an item exists in the Arraylist.

```
private void AddItems(object o)
{
if(!Arraylist1.Contains(o))
{
Arraylist1.Add(o);
}
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.contains(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: may be, but Arraylist.add returns an int, not bool ;)

Comment: I mean, for the OP to understand if the addition happened? :)

Comment: it depends how you design the api. by the way nice to see you :)

Answer (score 1):

In this code, I sort the `ArrayList` first. Then I compare `contacts[i]` with `contacts[i - 1]`

```
contacts.Sort(); // First Sort the array

for (int i=1; i <= contacts.Count-1; i++)
{
 Console.WriteLine(contacts[ i ]);
 Console.WriteLine(contacts[ i-1] );
 if(contacts[ i ].ToString() == contacts[ i-1 ].ToString())
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Duplicate: "+contacts[ i ]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using linq:

```
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList { 1, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5 };

        var x = from l in list.OfType<int>()
                group l by l into g
                where g.Count() > 1
                select g.Key;

        if (x.Count() > 0)
        {
           // Duplicate found
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a function that checks that returns boolean that is it defined or not such as Is_It_Defined. After that, you can use an if-statement to check before any operations you want.